# What does a phonemic rewrite mean?

Tags: phonology, terminology, phonemes

We have been doing phonemic rules in class, and our professor says to write a "phonemic rewrite" of words based on these rules, where these words are written like so "/_/". While I understand the concept of phonemes and their representation in the slashes, I dont understand it when words are represented in those slashes or what a phonemic rewrite is. Can someone please elaborate on this? Unfortunately, my textbook does not cover it.

Comment: What language are the words in? English? You didn't say. Your professor told you that phonemics was different from language to language, right? So there's no such thing as a "phonemic rewrite" in general -- instead there are specific phonemic rewrites for every single language. Including English. Reread your textbook to find out more about phonemes. The point of the exercise is not to improve your skill at "phonemic rewriting", but rather to get you to think about the **sounds** of words and how to represent them.

Comment: Same as a phonemic transcription?

Comment: For example, she wrote "madder" as /mædəɹ/ and I am confused on why the flap is replaced with "d" but for "matter" it is written as /mætəɹ/ and the flap is replaced with a "t". I don't quite understand the point of these. And I did read my textbook... I didn't understand what the purpose of this sort of transcription is because the words sound the same.

Comment: "Phonemic rewrite" seems like a strange choice of words. "Phonemic transcription" is a very common and standard term in linguisitcs. The choice of `d` or `t` or `ɾ` depends on things such as the dialect of English in question and the preferred IPA schema. IPA is just an alphabet and counter to what many non linguists believe, not everybody uses the IPA in the same way even for the same dialect of the same language. Especially for **phonemic** transcription. Take a look at en.wiktionary.org which uses it differently to any print dictionary I've ever seen for instance.